# Do Until Selection Value equals the For Each value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm currently trying to use a Do Until within a For each but I'm having a problem. What I'm trying is to Do Until selection value equals the value selected for the For each section in the following code:

```
Private Sub Copiar()

Dim Eselect As Variant
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim Col As Integer

Eselect = Array(CBE1.Value, CBE2.Value, CBE3.Value, CBE4.Value, CBE5.Value)

For Each vItem In Eselect
    Range("C2").Select
    Do Until Selection.Value = vItem.Value
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    Col = ActiveCell.Column
    Columns(Col).Copy
    Sheets(2).Active
    Range("A1").Select
    If Range("A1") = "" Then
        Columns(Col).Copy
    Else
        Do Until Selection.Value = ""
            Offset.Selection(0, 1) = Selection.Value
        Loop
        Columns(Col).Copy
   End If
Next
```

End Sub

The problem is specifically where is says "Do Until Selection.Value = vItem.Value" because I can't use vItem.Value and I don't know what I should use for to search until it find the value that For Each has selected. (I'm obviously just learning VBA).

The whole idea is for it to search a specific value (multiple times, one for each ComboBox Value: CBEi) in a row and return the column, then copy that column on another sheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Vicente.

Comment: `vItem.Value` --> `vItem`. that's it. But try to rewrite your code and get rid of the `Select` stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know how to replace the Select Stuff.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, everything works just fine. Thank you.